# Listing soft-deleted Azure storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cli, soft-delete, powershell-core

Do you know a way of listing soft-deleted Azure storage accounts?

In a nutshell, I deleted a storage account from the portal, now I try to re-create it and the operation is disallowed. I don't think it's a name collision as I use fairly long names for the storage accounts.

Any help is highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: soft-delete is actually for blob-level and container-level, not for the storage account level. You'd better check the name by using azure portal or powershell to see if it's already used.

Comment: @Ivan Yang thanks for the valuable answer. Actually, the screen-shot in my question shows that the storage name is already taken. But, I'm pretty sure no one could reserve the name for a very short period of time after a deleted the storage.

Comment: Just search it from azure portal to make sure that. Otherwise, it might be a temp issue.

Comment: Do you know if there is a screen in the portal to list soft-deleted storages? I know the way for log-analytics work-spaces and KeyVaults. But, couldn't find a way of seeing deleted storages in the portal.

Comment: yes we can. But if the storage account is garbage collected, we have no change to check them. You can follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-recover#recover-a-deleted-account-from-the-azure-portal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `soft-delete` is actually for `blob-level` and `container-level`, not for the storage account level. You'd better check the name by using azure portal or powershell to see if it's already used.

If you want to check the deleted storage account, you can follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-recover#recover-a-deleted-account-from-the-azure-portal). One thing need to know, if the deleted storage account is garbage collected, then we have no chance to find it.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to storage accounts and press Recover, then it will show you your recently deleted storage accounts (14days).

I am here because I too am looking for a way to purge these soft-deleted storage accounts.

Its not an obvious feature like on key vaults or soft-deleted backups, where you can do something about it.

It looks like they currently force you to keep it for 14 days. Which isnt all bad, but different from their design choice of other products.