# How to permanently purge deleted Azure Storage Account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I'd like to re-use the name of the storage account since it's tied to other configs. Looks like it' held for 14 days even after delete.

Is there a way to purge a deleted storage account so that the name becomes available again?

Preferraby in the UI or az CLI?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73136294/188096. TLDR; it is not possible to do so currently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @**Gaurav Mantri** for leading into right direction. Making it as a solution to help others also.
**Yes it is not possible to do so currently.**

Refer these [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66471621/listing-soft-deleted-azure-storage-accounts/73136294#73136294) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867938/storage-account-name-already-taken-after-being-deleted-from-another-tenant).

```
Looks like it' held for 14 days even after delete.
```

yes, as you said it last for 14days after deletion as shown in below image Deleted storage account (last 14 days).

[image]

```
I'd like to re-use the name of the storage account since it's tied to other configs.
```

I am just suggesting that if it is tied to other configs then you can restore that storage with in 14days and you can use as Purge is not possible right now.

[image]